# Type mismatch with type projection

Tags: scala, path-dependent-type, type-projection

I'm having a compiler **type mismatch error** that I do not understand.

Given the following definition of an `Elem` and a factory (`Companion`):

```
object Elem {
  trait Companion[E[~] <: Elem[~]] {
    def apply[S](peer: E[S]#Peer): E[S] // wrap a peer in its elem
  }
}
trait Elem[S] {
  type Peer
}
```

And given for example an `Obj` with attributes and a peer type `Expr`:

```
trait Expr[S, A]

trait Obj[S] {
  // query an attribute by key
  def attr[E[~] <: Elem[~]](key: String)
                           (implicit c: Elem.Companion[E]): Option[E[S]#Peer]
}
```

I should be able to do the following:

```
// process elements with peer `Expr[~, A]`
trait Impl[S, A, E[~] <: Elem[~] { type Peer = Expr[~, A] }] {
  implicit def companion: Elem.Companion[E]

  def test(obj: Obj[S]): Unit =
    obj.attr[E]("foo").fold(()) { ex =>
      val newElem = companion[S](ex)
    }
}
```

This last bit fails with the brilliant error message:

`<console>:62: error: type mismatch;
 found   : E[S]#Peer
    (which expands to)  Expr[S,A]
 required: E[S]#Peer
    (which expands to)  Expr[S,A]
             val newElem = companion[S](ex)
                                        ^`

Comment: Already saw same error in own project but unfortunately don't remember how fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reduced your example to the following:

```
trait Elem {
    type Peer
}

trait Impl[E[~] <: Elem {type Peer = ~}] {
    def foo[R](peer: E[R]#Peer)

    foo[Int](??? : E[Int]#Peer)
}
```

where scalac gives

```
Error:(12, 18) type mismatch;
 found   : this.scala.Peer
    (which expands to)  Int
 required: this.Peer(in method foo)
    (which expands to)  R
    foo[Int](??? : E[Int]#Peer)
             ^^
```

I'm not sure, but this looks like a Scala bug, since `R` isn't even in scope at the site of the error -- it seems to have leaked out. Scala seems to be failing to perform the substitution `R = Int` inside the refinement, allowing the parameter `R` to remain.

Comment: [I've made an issue for this](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9222) so we'll see whether people agree that this is a bug.